# Apply Regex in filter() in exchangelib

Tags: python, exchangelib

I am working on a script that needs to filter subject using regex. Does exchangelib support that? If so, can I get some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are [not supported in EWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648123/regular-expression-credit-card-search-using-exchange-web-services), so you can't do the filtering server-side. You'll have to pull all items and do the filtering client-side:

```
for item in account.inbox.all():
    if re.match(r'some_regexp', item.subject):
        # Do something
```

If you expect to match only very few items, you could optimize by first fetching only the subject field, and then full items:

```
matches = []
for item in account.inbox.all().only('subject'):
    if re.match(r'some_regexp', item.subject):
        matches.append(item)
full_items = account.fetch(matches)
```